# get xml data from res folder and parse it using libxml2 - Tizen

Tags: c, libxml2, tizen

I want to parse an offline xml file added to the res folder and parse it using **libxml2**. In examples and documents it says "xmlReadFile" function can get data from anything even form network address. But I am unsuccessful so far to read data from online and from res folder.

Heres how I'm tryring:

```
xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
xmlNode *root_element = NULL;
char *loc = "http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/simple.xml";//"data.xml";//

doc = xmlReadFile(loc, NULL, 0);

if (doc == NULL) {
   dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "GG", "error: could not parse file.");
 }
else {

       dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "GG", "success parse file.");
}


root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
```

I kept a data named xml file from on res folder and tried as shown in comment. with network privilege added whatever I try everytime it prints "`couldn't parse`" message.

How to resolve it and get an xml file read?

Comment: I don't think that `xmlReadFile` knows what to do with an `http` URL, only with a `file` URL.

Comment: You maybe correct, but in existing example it is written like this. I also tried with "data.xml" part. Can you please suggest a way to link the file with an example address?

Comment: Try to get the error message printed to stderr. If that's not possible, install your own error handler with `xmlSetGenericErrorFunc` and log the messages to other channels.

Comment: I can add the error messages from log but I dont know which part is related to the 'xmlReadFfile' function. If the above methods are correct then I can check all initial error messages.

Comment: Sorry to be a day late getting back to you, but if it were me, I'd use the curl API to grab the remote doc into memory, and then call `xmlReadMemory` on the buffer.